# How can I centrally position a widget in Flutter and then position other widgets relative to it?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to center a widget on the screen and then position another widget with relative spacing from there. However, whenever I try to create relative spacing and position another widget, it consistently shifts upward by the height of that widget.

[image]

Let me explain with code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        CenterWidget(),
        BottomWidget(),
      ],
    )));
  }
}

class CenterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class BottomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to position the `BottomWidget` with a spacing of 50 pixels from the `CenterWidget`, but whenever I place the `BottomWidget`, the `CenterWidget` consistently moves upward by the height of the `BottomWidget`. However, I want to keep the `CenterWidget` fixed at the center of the screen. I'm unsure about how to achieve this.

How can I center a widget on the screen and then position another widget with a fixed spacing from that widget?

https://dartpad.dev/?

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour is expected when you have multiple children inside the column.

With your simple example, without app bar or anything special, then I would suggest a simple try:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        CenterWidget(),
        BottomWidget(),
      ],
    )));
  }
}

class CenterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(children: [
      SizedBox(height: size.height / 2 - 100),
      Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's a huge help.
However, I feel that there is a slightly easier way to specify the height for `CenterWidget`.